# Curved image, need straight iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

First image is original image and have side curve.

Second image is same image but have effect side curve is straight.

How can I get this effect in swift code.

I try CIFilter but with no results.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Straight image]

Comment: This document seems to contain private information. Please don't upload things like that to the open internet.

Comment: Your question is valid. But please exercise a bit more care in framing the question, and please don't use sensitive material for your example. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to combine VisionKit and CIPerspectiveCorrection

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren yes I use vision kit and CIPerspectiveCorrection to crop correct position of scanned image. CIPerspectiveCorrection only crop in perspective, not stretch it. This document is fake not real document. thanks